# Deploy React-(Create-React-App),Express.js and MySQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

How to deploy react (Create-React-App), Express.js and MySQL ?

I tried deploying on cPanel. do I have to change it to Production mode? 
how do I access the API on Express.js? do I have to create a sub domain on Express.js?

because so far I only use the library which is concurrently and nodemon. and on React.js I added a proxy like this:
"proxy": "http: // localhost: 5000", where localhost: 5000 has a port from Express.js

Package.json script in server.js

```
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others \" npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

Package.json script in React

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

My App :

- Client > folder react app > Package.json,Src
- Node modules > npm from server
- Server > Express config,Routes,Controller
- .babelrc
- server.js
- package.json

Answer (score 0):

Do you have terminal access on the cPanel? If yes, then

1. Start your node server (Using PS or Nodemon)
2. If your cPanel is using any kind of a server (`nginx` or `Apache webserver` for example), then configure the server file to redirect to `localhost:5050` on `*:80` and `*:443`
3. Configure your Express.js to serve on port `5050`

And that's it.

Comment: yess i can use ssh using putty. so i dont need sub domain for get data from express.js? how can i configure `*:80` and `*:443` ?

Comment: You don't need a subdomain, by default the domain uses the *:80(HTTP) and *443(HTTPS) ports. You need to configure those in your server. Are you using Express js as your server (wherein you are serving the static files from the Express js app itself)?

Comment: i dont use static file in express.js. so how can i configure ?

Comment: How are you serving your `react` app to the users?

Comment: so the user can access react app with url localhost:3000

Comment: I updated the question for more detail please help me :(

Comment: Simplest solution is for you to change the proxy to localhost:80

Comment: iam using 2 port broo, localhost:3000 for client and localhost:5000 for server. does it really not need a sub domain? because I can access 2 different urls, namely localhost: 3000 as a client that displays the website I created and localhost: 5000 as a resful API server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188581/discussion-between-farisdev-and-varun-agarwal).