# How do I deploy ReactJs + Node app onto remote server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment

Assuming I'm not using any third party service, just a dedicated server, how do I go about doing this? I'd like to use [this](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) as an example. In it, there's a build folder. I understand I can pretty much just copy paste the contents of this into the `public_html` of the remote server after doing `npm run build` but then there's the `/server` folder which is using node and possibly interacting with the database, can't be put in with the rest of the build js.

My best guess is that I would `npm run build` and ftp the contents of the `build` folder to `public_html` on the remote server then I would put the contents of the server folder onto another subdomain and then ssh into the server and do `npm start` in said subdomain? Or possibly have it in a subfolder of the `public_html`. I'm from a php background and used to vanilla js + php so any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah have a separate subdomain 'server', 'api' or whatever, have that running on the remote server. 
the build folder will just be the ui which you can push to the 'dashboard','UI' folder.

Comment: I feel like most axios/fetch requests I see have the url as `/api/users` as opposed to `https://api.something.com:3000/users`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create build folder in react side by running

```
npm run build
```

then add these lines of code in the node side in app.js/index.js

```
app.use(express.static("<your_react_app_folder>/build"));
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  const path = require("path");
  app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendfile(path, resolve(__dirname, "../<your_react_app_folder>", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

Then deploy it to heroku/remote server.

Note: remember to remove /build line from .gitignore file

Comment: Looking through it, I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54743029/deploy-react-create-react-app-express-js-and-mysql I suppose I could redirect the `/api` subfolder to the url on which the node server is running? In that case the server wouldn't have to be on another subdomain

Comment: @Dan185 this is exactly what is happening we are using proxy point to server domain so when we make request in client side for something like /api/users it is actually making request to http://server_domain/api/users and fetching data using axios and giving it to react app

Comment: I will want to set up a proxy then to allow the front end subdomain to communication with the api on the other subdomain